# Javascript not removing DIV by ID

Tags: javascript

My javascript is supposed to remove a DIV from it's id when the time is past 20 hours. But it doesn't seem to work with following code.

JS:

```
if (new Date().getHours() > 20) {
document.getElementById("carttext").remove();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block block-cart-header" style="padding: 0px;" id="carttext">
    <div class="block-content" style="background: none; padding: 2px; min-height: 10px; text-align: center; background-color: #e2e2e2;">
        <span style="font-size: 10px;" id="ordertext">Modtag <span id="day1"></span>, bestil før</span><br> 
        <b id="countdown1" style="color: black;"></b>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in console ? This should be working..

Comment: How is that JavaScript being run?

Comment: I am guessing that your javascript is running before your html.

Comment: Make sure to either put your script at the very end of your `body` element, or to use something like `window.onload = function() { ..... }`.

Comment: It's all inside the body, using magento i couldn't find any workarounds.

Comment: At **the end** of the `body`? Anyway, try to put your code inside an anonymous function assigned to `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible scenario and most common mistake could be that your JavaScript is processed even before the DOM element is created, this means your JavaScript is looking for an element and removing it even before it is created (*This should log an error message in console*). After JS is processed, your DOM is created and so is your `ElementById("carttext")`. That is why you are not seeing the results you expect.

What you should do is make sure `<script>` tags are placed at bottom of your HTML document.
Also, log the messages of your actions in console, it will help you a lot tracing the errors.

Edit 1: The coders in comments are saying the same thing, make sure you fix that.